# Beamer: show references *all at once* on final slide

Tags: beamer

I have a slide at the end of my presentation generated by ... :

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
\end{frame}
```

It uncovers each item one-by-one, but I want it to show them all at once. I can't figure out how to do this. Help?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a minimal working example -> https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/124842

Answer (score 2):

My crystal ball says: use

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}
```

before the reference frame.